# AWS ubuntu lnmp+ wordpress down

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I made a mistake yesterday. I tried to increase the volume of existing micro t2 instance by detaching the old volume and attaching a new volume. However, I didn't pay attention to snapshot and now my website is down because "failed to establish connection with database"

```
150929 09:41:52 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/var

150929  9:41:52 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
150929  9:41:52 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
150929  9:41:52 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
150929  9:41:52 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
150929  9:41:52 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150929  9:41:52 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.42-log'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
150929  9:41:53 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Normal shutdown
150929  9:41:53 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
150929  9:41:53 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

When I tried to stop mysql , I got following :

```
Stoping LNMP...
Stoping nginx...  done
 * MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Gracefully shutting down php-fpm  done
Starting LNMP...
Starting nginx...  done
Starting MySQL
. * The server quit without updating PID file    (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid).
Starting php-fpm  done
```

Hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database was on that volume.
Check if you have automatically created snapshots (EC2 - Snapshots on the right).
If you have it then:

- Select the snapshot
- From "Actions" at the top select "Create volume"
- Set parameters and create the volume

Now "stop" the instance (don't terminate!), once stopped - detach the current volume and attache the one you created from the snapshot.

Start the instance and check if it works now.

But if you don't have the snapshots then there is nothing to do - you just need to setup the database from scratch (create the new database, create tables, etc). 
And if mysql doesn't work after stop / start - try to re-install it, it should re-create the data folders which are probably missing now.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have a snapshot. However, I found  some mysql information. Now I think they probably already missed.